# .htaccess Dynamic sub domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, dns, url-rewriting, subdomain

I want to have dynamic subdomains, such as:
(.*).mydomain.com

that I can retreive with `$_GET['subdomain']`. I have added an wildcard DNS record (* A xx.xx.xx.xx), and now for every subdomain I go to (e.g. test.mydomain.com) all I get is:

`Apache is functioning normally`

I have tried this code in .htaccess, but nothing seems to help:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$    http://www.mydomain.com/?subdomain=%1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something more like this?

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !subdomain=
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?subdomain=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I dont get my normal homepage, I still get `Apache is functioning normally`, so it's not really working as I hoped it would.

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar and you have your server setup to accept requests from *.mydomain.com? It needs to be aliased otherwise the default vhost will handle **all** of those requests.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/38fa10 - this is what I had added to my DNS, what else do I need to check?

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar you need to check you apache's set, (that's what I meant by "server"). Apache has to know that when it gets a request for the host "blahblah.mydomain.com" to serve the same site as "www.mydomain.com". It doesn't happen automatically.

Comment: how do I make sure it serves the same website?

Comment: @ArkoElsenaar something like this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html